# How to remap objects in typescript?

Tags: typescript

What is TypeScript way to remap objects?

How can I achieve the same functionality but keeping it type safe ?

```
type FooBar = 'Foo' | 'Bar';
type Obj = { [key in FooBar]?: string[] }

const obj: Obj = {};
const newObj: Obj = {};

for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = ...
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAQgQwE5QLxQOTztqAHxxVWwG4AoUSKAeQCMArTKAbygG0BrCEKAJYA7WAlIBdAPwAuKAGdgqYQHNO4qAF9KlAMZwhCqHGazGLLGw1U9B4FCEQA7mdPNWlqpQBmcdAAobQ15+YSNmAEp2SigYwS8oP2MmADoAC2Q5OkchAAVUOEhUUD9g8Mi2aNiqwLsAN2QAGwBXaCwknj5xKiqqgHpeiAAPRWQoHUadJobkYAF9OShgOCh65uhOZM31ZCEAE0EDCCKjIQaQ+NWWwQWhODshKemGBohKnriEy4hyt-eqh2czA6IHUWC+3T+WiqWg0QA)

Currently I'm seeing typescript error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type 'Obj'.   No index signature with
>   a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Obj'.

I understand why `key` is `string` type not union but don't understand how to achieve same functionality with valid typescript:

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access the type with runtime code. This is just not possible since it is not avaliable during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in your object are of Type FooBar, that is why you get "No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Obj'."

In order for the above code to work, you can type cast your key to FooBar:

```
type FooBar = 'Foo' | 'Bar';
type Obj = { [key in FooBar]?: string[] }

const obj: Obj = {};
const newObj: Obj = {};

for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key as FooBar)) {
        const value = ...
```

[Your same Playground example with typecast](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAQgQwE5QLxQOTztqAHxxVWwG4AoUSKAeQCMArTKAbygG0BrCEKAJYA7WAlIBdAPwAuKAGdgqYQHNO4qAF9K2ygGM4QhVDjNZjFljYaq+w8ChCIAd3NnmrK1UoAzOOgAUtka8-MLGzACU7JRQsYLeUP4mTAB0ABbIcnROQgAKqHCQqKD+IRFRbDFx1UH2AG7IADYArtBYyTx8UJmiSGjiVNXVAPTDEAAeishQuk26zY3IwAIGclDAcFANLdCcKfvqyEIAJoKGEMXGQo2hCdutgmtCcPZCC4sMjRBVQ-GJ9xAKj9ftVHC5mJ1+D08BJWADBiCtNUtFogA)